# Localhost issue: .NET API endpoints giving 403 error but a doc page from the same project loads. Both are under localhost

Tags: iis, localhost, asp.net, api

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this, but doing so with this hope that it might relate to some kind of IIS settings!

I have .NET website setup with SQL Server database. This is basically an API project. The documentation part loads fine under `localhost`, but when I am trying to invoke an endpoint from here, I am getting a forbidden (403) error. The endpoint too runs under `localhost`.

The documentation URL on localhost is `http://localhost/swagger/ui/index` and this loads fine.

Above changes to `http://localhost/swagger/ui/index#!/Part/Part_Search` when I open any section with an endpoint test section under it. This also loads fine.

But as I enter a value to test the endpoint, the 403 error appears.

Screenshot:
[image]

I tried all recommended IIS fixes but nothing worked! So, I really have no idea if this is related to any configuration of my PC / IIS or there is any restriction imposed in the API end points (Controllers).

I know I should not request like this, but really looking for an early solution. Please advise.

Comment: 403 is permission denied. Check things like token, credentials, and so on...

Comment: Yes, after getting your message I rechecked and it was indeed the Authorization Token that I was missing! Thank you very much!!!